# Smooth rotation transition CSS3?

Tags: html, css, transition, smoothing

I am rotating my images when hovered and I want the transition to be smooth so this is what I tried:

```
<div class="latest-thumbs">
    <img src="images/thumbs/thumb01.jpg" alt="thumb" class="rotate" />
    <img src="images/thumbs/thumb01.jpg" alt="thumb" class="rotate" />
    <img src="images/thumbs/thumb01.jpg" alt="thumb" class="rotate" />
</div><!-- end latest-thumbs -->
```

CSS:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;

    -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
    -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
    transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

My images rotate when hovered, so there is no problem there, only, the transition is not smooth. Any ideas on how to fix this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wntX4/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

change all your transition css property (replace ease with linear)

```
transition: 300ms ease all;
```

with

```
transition: 300ms linear all;
```

refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)

**Update**

your transition is only for opacity property that is working in the right way

Comment: Tried this but it's not changing anything. :(

Comment: have you tried with different values? ease-in,ease-out.. can you post a  fiddle with the error?

Comment: Then you need to explain what you mean by "not smooth"

Comment: I mean the "transition: 300ms linear all;" part doesn't seem to work at all. I'll try making a fiddle.

Comment: your transition is only for opacity property that is working in the right way

Comment: I'll update my answer, remembar to accept the answer that you choose as best to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `transform: translate` (and of course browser-specific prefixes). [This article](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) is pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed this in your fiddle and it works:

```
.rotate:hover {
            transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            -khtml-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(50%);
            transition: all 2s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
            -o-transition: all 2s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
            -khtml-transition: all 2s ease;
        }
```

I think that browser was firing 2 hovers at once. It's 1 year old but someong might fail into this again.